# iTunes 12.2 broke the shared library feature from Mac to Windows

Tags: macos, itunes, windows

My music is stored on my iMac, and I also have a PC with windows that I use for video games, I leave iTunes opened on my iMac when I'm on my PC so that I can listen to songs while gaming.

Here's my iTunes Sharing preferences on my iMac
[image]

The shared playlist appears on my PC, as you can see here
[image]

But clicking on it only shows a spinning indicator and then gives up after about 20 seconds, not showing the library on my iMac.
[image]

Yes, both iTunes versions are exactly 12.2 on each machine, and this only happens since 12.2. Sharing my library worked fine before this update.

Answer (score 1):

Apple removed Home Sharing for music with 12.2. The theory I've read on the Apple forums is that this is one of the concessions they had to make with the music labels in order to get Apple Music off the ground.

Here's a cnet article that mentions the feature change:

http://www.cnet.com/news/itunes-users-hit-stumbling-blocks-with-arrival-of-apple-music/

Edit: Home Sharing for music was indeed removed with the latest updates.

http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/07/eddy-cue-apple-working-to-bring-back-itunes-home-sharing-for-ios-9/

Comment: This article seems to be false. The sharing still works, but only from Mac to Mac. (I have another Mac in my house and it works with iTunes 12.2)